# Convert column type from FLOAT to MONEY in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I need to change a column type from FLOAT to MONEY, but I get the error:

[Link to the example:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8fff987eae5a54a3dd73f79dc04e2704)

**ERROR:  operator does not exist: money >= double precision
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

Current table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_settings
(
    ...
    price FLOAT DEFAULT 0 CHECK (price >= 0)
);
```

Here is the migration part:

```
ALTER TABLE user_settings
ALTER COLUMN price TYPE money USING price::text::money,
ALTER COLUMN price SET DEFAULT 0.0::money;
ALTER TABLE user_settings ADD CHECK (price >= 0.0::money);
```

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hey, thanks, I saw your comment under other similar questions. The thing is I can't change the requirement.

Comment: @КаринаБаринова the link is to the PostgreSQL wiki, not some personal opinion. The PostgreSQL wiki itself tells you to stop using `money`. You encountered one of the reasons. Another problem is that you can't even use it to calculate VAT or other taxes due to its limited precision. Or convert between currencies. You can't use `money` for any meaningful calculation involving real money

Comment: Do you really have a requirement that tells you to use a datatype that creates new problems? Or do you have a requirement that tells you to store a value and the currency for this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to numeric then to money:

```
 alter table user_settings
 alter column price type numeric using price::numeric::money;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=039305b794a852cb3bd0fd8fbde64bf3)

> Values of the numeric, int, and bigint data types can be cast to
> money. Conversion from the real and double precision data types can be
> done by casting to numeric first, for example:
>
> SELECT '12.34'::float8::numeric::money;

Comment: And then start fixing all the new problems you encounter…